# How they did this step in photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs5

Hey I seen this article in web and trying to do this animated gif but i stucked in middle and i wonder how they did this step ? Article link  http://goo.gl/kTWfmG 
succesfully done the above steps?

Image Step link -  [I stuck in this step](http://i57.tinypic.com/r0xf8n.png)

Answer (score -1):

Your question isn't clear enough. Which step are you stuck on? I saw the image step link but cannot identify it. Please provide step number and the sub title mentioned in that tutorial.

EDIT: for the duplication step,all you have to do is make the first shape then duplicate it (Control + J in windows) then use Transform Tool (Control + T) to rotate it, then you have to press control + alt + shift + T to duplicate & transform the previous layer, it will duplicate and change the angle which will give u the desired effect.

Refer this video for detailed explanation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM6h4aE2Vx8

Let me know if you need more help :)

Comment: Step : 4 Creating shape tick marks under layer mask and Step 2: Styling Shapes Duplicating Layers in that article

Comment: @user3416656 Edited the answer , check it out.